# Need to remove www for only one sub directory from a domain

Tags: web-hosting, htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, no-www

I have a domain like `www.example.com`. I need to remove `www.` from specified sub folder by using a `.htaccess` file.

Example :

1. `www.example.com/blog` should redirect to `example.com`
2. All other sub folders will not redirect in url like `www.example.com/forum` will remain untouched.
3. `www.example.com` will remain untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a rewrite rule like this in place in the `.htaccess` file.  In this example "example.com" is the domain name and "subdirectory" is the name of the folder for which you want to remove the "www".

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^subdirectory(\/.*)?$ http://example.com/subdirectory$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not working because main domain and sub domain are in different server. Can you please help.

Comment: You could put that rule on the server with the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your control panel and create a redirect without www